# Starting previously stopped EC2 instances by tags with ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to create a playbook or role that lets me start previously stopped EC2 instances with ansible by tag for example (EC2 instances ares assigned to static groups in the inventory through tags). The `ec2.ini` file is changed to also return information about stopped instances. The only similar examples I have seen so far rely on `ec2_facts` to get `instance_ids`.

The official [example](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_module.html) on the ansible website assumes the `region` and `instance_ids` are already known in advance/hardcoded.

```
- name: Start sandbox instances
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - 'i-xxxxxx'
      - 'i-xxxxxx'
      - 'i-xxxxxx'
    region: us-east-1
  tasks:
    - name: Start the sandbox instances
      ec2:
        instance_ids: '{{ instance_ids }}'
        region: '{{ region }}'
        state: running
        wait: True
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
        assign_public_ip: yes
  role:
    - do_neat_stuff
    - do_more_neat_stuff
```

Preferably I am looking for a solution where I can get the necessary variables from the dynamic inventory for example, if possible at all.

Comment: I believe you can iterate through the tag and use `ansible_ec2_instance_id` for it. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existing EC2 instances can be started with the play below, without the need to hardcode instance identifiers or the EC2 region.

```
--- ec2.yml
- hosts: aws
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: start EC2 instance
    local_action:
      module: ec2
        state=running
        region={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ec2_region'] }}
        instance_ids={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ec2_id'] }}
    tags:
      - start-instance
```

Assuming dynamic instances are tagged the following command will start instances:

`$ ansible-playbook -i inventory --limit [instance static group name] --tags start-instance ec2.yml`

Comment: What if we want to start the instances which has `elastic IPs` and are listed in the `hosts` file under a `group` say `[stopped-instances]`

Comment: Where is documented the part :
instance_ids={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ec2_id'] }}
?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to tell the dynamic inventory script to return hosts that are down.  That is set to "False" in the **ec2.ini** file.  Change it to "True":

```
# By default, only EC2 instances in the 'running' state are returned. Set
# 'all_instances' to True to return all instances regardless of state.
all_instances = True
```

Here is the playbook I use:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ ip_list | default( 'ec2' ) }}"
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Start instance
    ec2:
      state: running
      instance_id: "{{ ec2_id }}"
      key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
      region: "{{ region }}"
      wait: true
    delegate_to: localhost
```

**key_name** and **region** are defined in my group_vars/all file, **ec2_id** comes from ansible with the host information, and **ip_list** is defined on the command line.

Comment: very good point about the .ini file. Could you add examples about the group vars/all and the command lines/ how do you run it?

Comment: The only relevant things in `groupvars/all` are `key_name` and `region`.  The key_name is set when we build the inventory, so we can use a different keys with different inventories.  The command line is just `ansible-playbook start_instances -e "ip_list=first,second,third"`.